OpenAI Whisper split audio / video File into chunks of 25MB in node js
I currently have an object of type File and can access its buffer which I want to split into chunks of 25MB due to whisper's limitations. However I tried with subarray but only the first chunk could be processed by Whisper (I guess is due to the file's metadata being only in the first chunk). If you have an idea on how to do it in node js, I would appreciate it :)


function splitBuffer(buffer, chunkSize) {
    const chunks = [];
    let position = 0;

    while (position < buffer.length) {
        const end = Math.min(position + chunkSize, buffer.length);
        const chunk = buffer.subarray(position, end);
        chunks.push(chunk);
        position = end;
    }

    return chunks;
}



